# Skype crash in Mac OS X 10.8.3

Tags: macos, skype

I am facing the problem on the login of skype, I've searched on the Skype site and found this [link](http://community.skype.com/t5/Mac/New-update-for-mac-quits-unexpectedly-just-after-sign-in/td-p/637711).

However, I'm not able to figure out what causes this issue.

I'm using Mac OS X 10.8.3

[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wm5v6bgvfpz9214/SkypeCrash.rtf) is the link for the crash report.

[image: Crash Screen shot]

**Update**

[image: This alert also getting additional information]

**Since your report shows crash in Thread 0, it might have to do with some other application is garbing all ports. Disable all programs specially if you using VMware, Parallels, or VirtualBox to see if the problem is there. – Borderline 8 mins ago**

Based On the above comment :

[image: Screen 1]
[image: Screen 2]

Comment: Welcome to this site! Can you please add some more details about your problem (screen shots, error messages etc.) and the specific steps you've already tried to solve it? The more detail the better, we love detail here and it increases the chance that somebody will find a solution. You may also find ideas on how to improve the question in [ask].

Comment: Does it happen on start-up? If no, when does it happen? Did you already re-install the application?

Comment: @Robuust  after launching the skype within 30 t0 60 seconds i got this crash

Comment: Please disable all other VoiP, that might be conflicting.

Comment: Update skype to Version 6.3.0.582 (you have 6.2.60)

Comment: @Borderline okay i will try and update you and at present i didn't have any VoiP in Mac

Comment: @Borderline 6.3.0.583 also getting the same crash

Comment: Since your report shows crash in Thread 0, it might have to do with some other application is garbing all ports. Disable all programs specially if you using VMware, Parallels, or VirtualBox to see if the problem is there.

Comment: @Borderline i check i used few of other apps only i updated my screens currently the threads are running in my mac

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8026/discussion-between-borderline-and-spynet)

Comment: I see you found the problem = the call recorder :) I assume skype is looking for it, and it gets refused :(

Comment: @Borderline This alert i am getting past 6 months

Comment: @Borderline i solved that issue  Call recorder is the only problem ---- thanks lot to solve my issue and thanks for your patience to answer me and thanks !!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Still, it can be that software since it interacts with skype. Kill it and try this one:  http://www.kandasoft.com/kanda-apps/callnote/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you found the problem being the call recorder :) I assume skype is looking for it, and it gets refused.

Kill that application, and if you want a new recorder try this one.

http://www.kandasoft.com/kanda-apps/callnote/

Comment: How are you supposed to kill the call recorder if the program quits immediately every time?!

Comment: @JoelHuggins It's Skype which is crashing and CallRecorder seems to be the culprit. So killing CallRecorder should allow you to run Skype again.

Answer (score 1):

Skype stopped launching for me on Mac 10.8.3  and I tried reinstalling, deleting library skype files to no avail. But then after starting in safe mode ( power down, start, hold down shift key until apple and gear wheel appear) Skype worked perfectly and continues to do so after normal restart.